# How to get get top 10 retweeted tweets in a data set?

Tags: r, twitter

I am trying to find top 10 retweeted tweets from a dataframe of Tweets. I use the function which.max with the following code,

```
tweets.df[which.max(tweets.df$Retweets),n,10,]
```

but its showing the following error. Any help?

> Error in `[.data.frame`(tweets.df, which.max(tweets.df$Retweets), n, 10,  :
> unused argument (alist())

Comment: I think u need `dplyr::top_n`

Comment: I tried this, but not working   top_n(tweets.df$Retweets, n=10)

Comment: `tweets.df  %>% top_n(10, Retweets)`

Comment: add `dput(tweets.df)`